# Removing text via js and data posting

Tags: php, javascript, post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeLink()
{
    document.getElementById("tab2").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="forth.php" method="post">
<table width="600" border="1" id="tab2">


<?php

    foreach($_POST as $post2)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    echo $post2.'<br />';
    ?>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" onClick="removeLink(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    }

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Next" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</form>
</body>
```

this is my page third.php it redirect user to new page forth.php on forth.php i have following code

```php
<?php

print_r($_POST);

foreach($_POST as $key_post)
{
    echo $key_post.'<br>';
}

?>
```

the issue is on page `forth.php` it doesn't print anything even when I did `print_r($_POST);` it returned me empty array like Array(), and help why data is not saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's empty because you don't actually have any `<input name="foo" type="bar />` fields other than the submit button, so nothing is actually being posted.

You'll need to add some hidden fields:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $post2)
{
?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $post2.'<br />'; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key;?>" value="<?php echo $post2;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
... etc
```

Comment: great thanks a lot, yes i do not have any text boxes to post the data and text can not be saved eventually so i will have to do something like this...

Comment: i have one more thing to ask, the above code should be implemented into forth.php or this changes should be applied on third.php